# Warmup module not working in Orchard (404 Error)

Tags: module, content-management-system, orchardcms

I built an Intranet using Orchard 1.9 for our office and wanted to use the warmup module to load 3 main pages every 30 minutes or so (including home page /)

If I just add in / to the warm up line and only that it comes back with a 404 message which means it is not a valid page. Anyone having this issue because every url I try to use including the format they suggested is getting the 404 error and not a status of 200.

Thank you, additional information can be provided if requested.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Also, check the log files in the app_data folder.  That might give you a clue as to what went wrong.

Comment: Hey Mark Lybrand, thanks for the reply but we no longer are using it. Just wanted to swing in and let ya know. Thanks!